# Avoid useless copies of buffers

Tags: optimization

The other day I was looking at a opensource engine, basically it was uploading the image from a file to a RAM buffer adding some decoding while streaming (I assume this is done "in-cache" so I can't count the decoding as an extra copy), then the buffer was feeded to `glTexImage2D`.

According to GL specifications, `glTexImage2D` is free to keep a in-RAM copy of the image and wait for the best moment to upload it to the GPU.

So basically we have

- From disk to RAM
- From RAM to RAM
- From RAM to GPU

Thos are basically 4-5 BUS runs x Textures Size in megabytes  bandwith payload

3 copies of the same data.

Isn't there anyway to reduce the copies to

- From disk to RAM
- from RAM to GPU

Or even

- From disk to GPU

?

(Assuming hard-disk already have data in the correct memory layout and hence no decoding is necessary).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is using a PBO, Pixel Buffer Object.

You map a opengl buffer and put the image data into there. Then unmap and bind that buffer to `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` and call `glTexImage2D` with the `data` parameter set to `(void* )0`. This makes `glTexImage2D` use the buffer as the data source instead of the application memory. The `data` parameter is the offset into the buffer.

Because opengl was in charge of allocating that buffer and it's not mapped anymore it does not need to make a copy of the buffer.